# .NET: When does GC run? Memory leak?

Tags: .net, string, memory-leaks, immutability

I understand what immutability is, and how the String .NET class is special. The immutability makes it behave like a value type even though it's a reference type. Got it. The C# reference emphasizes this point (see [string (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx), emphasis added by me:

> Strings are immutable--the contents of a string object cannot be changed after the object is created, although the syntax makes it appear as if you can do this. For example, when you write this code, the **compiler actually creates a new string object to hold the new sequence of characters, and that new object is assigned to b. The string "h" is then eligible for garbage collection.**

Being a self-taught programmer I'm not well versed in garbage collectors and memory leaks and pointers and stuff. That's why I'm asking a question about it. The description of how the C# compiler automatically creates new string objects and abandons old ones makes it seem like a bunch of memory could get used up with abandoned string content. A lot of objects have dispose methods or destructors so that even the automated CLR garbage collector knows when and how to clean up after an object that isn't needed anymore. There is nothing like this for a String. I wanted to see what would actually happen if a created a program so that I could demostrate for myself and others that creating and immediately abandoning string objects can consume a lot of memory.

Here's the program:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ReadKey();
        int megaByte = (int)Math.Pow(1024, 2);
        string[] hog = new string[2048];
        char c;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2048; i++)
        {
            c = Convert.ToChar(i);
            Console.WriteLine("Generating iteration {0} (char = '{1}')", i, c);
            hog[i] = new string(c, megaByte);
            if ((i + 1) % 256 == 0) { 
                for (int j = (i - 255); j <= i; j++) { hog[j] = hog[i]; } }
            }
        Console.ReadKey();

        List<string> uniqueStrings = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2048; i++) {
            if (!uniqueStrings.Contains(hog[i])) { uniqueStrings.Add(hog[i]); }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("There are {0} unique strings in hog.", uniqueStrings.Count);
        Console.ReadKey();

        // Create a timer with an interval of 30 minutes 
        // (30 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 milliseconds)
        System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(30 * 60 * 1000);
        t.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(t_Elapsed);
        t.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting 30 minutes...");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void t_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Time's up. I'm collecting the garbage.");
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

It creates a destroys bunch of unique strings and only ends up with 8 unique strings in the hog array. In my tests the process was still holding on to 570 Mb to 1.1 Gb (it varied). The timer part waits 30 minutes while leaving the process active (not sleeping) and at the end of 30 minutes, the process was *still* holding on to all the extra memory until I forced collection. This makes it seem like the .NET garbage collector missed something. Lots of other places people say that calling GC.Collect() is something terrible. So the fact that the memory only seems to get reclaimed by forcing the collector using this method still makes it seem like something is wrong.

Comment: Wow. Huge essay for little purpose. Your first "immutable" sample is wrong. That's just changing the reference and has nothing to do with immutability.

Comment: It means garbage collection works, but doesn't run until it *needs* to.

Comment: I think that you could boil this down to a very short question: If a .NET process first uses a lot of memory and then releases the reference to that memory. How long will it take until the GC reclaims the memory? How long will the memory size of the process remain large? Is it ever released back to the OS? Try asking such a short question instead of this enormous text flow.

Comment: I wonder if you realize `1024^2` is `1026`, not `1048576`

Comment: I wonder if you realize 1024^2 is 1026, not 1048576 -- Yeah, I realize that. Just forget to change that in the first example.

Comment: I think that there is an interesting question here.... but could lose all the bits talking about immutable strings. I have updated the title for direction.

Comment: @pst: the only interesting thing I find here is that this is almost a transcript of the OP learning how GC works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just that the the garbage collector of your version of the CLR reacts to memory pressure, not elapsed time. Why spend precious CPU time cleaning up memory that isn't needed anyway?

Sure you could argue that it would be better to perform the GC when the program is "idle". The problem is, that you want to keep the GC algorithm as simple as possible (which usually means fast) and that the algorithm can't read your mind. It doesn't know when the application is doing "nothing constructive".

Answer (score 8):

Your post is quite a bit of bloat. In short you allocate a lot of memory while keeping references and then notice that the GC won't triggers even when they are no longer referenced, even when much time passes.

This means that the GC isn't triggered based on time, but just based on what allocations happen. And once no allocations happen it won't run. If you start allocating again the memory will eventually go down.

This is in no way related to immutability or strings in particular.

Comment: A bloated question about GC-string-bloat. :-)

Comment: "This is in no way related to immutability or strings in particular." Yes, it is. The immutability specifically of strings causes a unique case, at least in C# syntax, where an object is created and abandoned in a way that is not at all obvious. When assigning a string literal there is no "new" statement; when reassigning a new value you have lost any means of referencing the previous string object, even though you didn't do anything to explicitly dispose() or set to null or anything.

Comment: That's just how GC works. Why do you think there's any kind of memory leak?

Comment: Your post is quite a bit of bloat ... A bloated question ... Sheesh. No one is forcing you to read it. I just knew that if I didn't really clearly document how I came to my conclusion I would get flamed for making scandalous unfounded claims about the CLR garbage collector.

Comment: @jmh How are string literals relevant here? you're allocating your 2MB strings with `new`. String literals are interned, so they don't cause any additional allocations, but in your programs the only string literal is used for logging and irrelevant in the context of your question. Your program would exhibit exactly the same behavior with mutable arrays.

Answer (score 4):

Immutability means that

```
string a = "abc"; 
string b = a; 
a=a+"def";
```

creates a new string containing "abcdef", and assigns it to `a`. The value of `b` is unchanged, and still refers to a string containing "abc".

Comment: I believe the OP already knows this, but this reminder might be helpful for other future readers.

Comment: @WarrenP: How could you tell what the OP knows or doesn't with that wall of text he posted?

Comment: Because he says "I understand what immutability is", thus you telling him that he doesn't know what immutability is, is disengenuous. His post shows that he does realize that changing the value of B after assigning it to A, doesn't change A.

Comment: @WarrenP: my answer was based on his original post, not as edited. His original made no attempt to "change a string", only to assign a different string. My example shows an attempt to change a string and shows that a new string is created to hold the changes.

Comment: Oh yes. Time machine problems in my head again. Sorry.